# matplotlib, how to compress parts of x axis

Tags: python, matplotlib

Hey guys this is my first time posting here and hopefully this question isn't too trivial. I tried looking for a solution to this but couldn't find what I wanted.

I have this very simple code here which plots xy line graph

```
x = [1,2,3,10,11]
y = [1,2,3,4,5]

plt.plot(x,y)
plt.xticks(x)
```

The graph then looks like this:
[Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O7sta.png)

What I want to do is compress the x axis such that the spacing between each point is the same. E.g have the space between 3 to 10 be the same as the space between 1 to 2.

Is there a way to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

fig,ax = plt.subplots()

x = [1,2,3,10,11]
y = [1,2,3,4,5]

ax.plot(y,marker='o')
ax.set_xticks([i for i in range(len(y))])
ax.set_xticklabels(x)
plt.show()
```

I added the markers to visualise the data points better. The result looks like this:
[image: result of the posted code]

**EDIT**:

If you want to visualise that the axis is not continuous, you can find help in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32186074/2454357).

**EDIT2**:

In my example, I only passed the `y`-values to the `plot` function, which means that the `x`-values are implicitly calculated to be [1,2,3,4,5]. You can of course also pass the `x`-values for each plot command explicitly and thereby variate at which `x`-value which plot starts. For the example in your comment, this would be:

```
fig,ax = plt.subplots()

y1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
x1 = [i for i in range(len(y1))]
y2 = [2,3,4,5,6]
x2 = [i+1 for i in range(len(y2))]

xticks = list(set(x1+x2)) #or more explicit: [i for i in range(6)]
xtick_labels = [1,2,3,10,11,12]

ax.plot(x1,y1,marker='o')
ax.plot(x2,y2,marker='x')
ax.set_xticks(xticks)
ax.set_xticklabels(xtick_labels)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Hi Sorry, but I have a follow up question that came up, and I am not really sure how to solve it. Basically I want to add another line to the same plot but I want it to start at x = 2. But if I have  y1 = [2,3,4,5,6] and I add ax.plot(y1) it will start the line at x = 1. I tried also doing ax.plot(x1,y1) where x1 = [2,3,10,11,12] but that leads to having the original problem of this post for the new line added. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: @MoustafaNassar have a look at the edit I made to the answer.