# Plot a line chart on Python with a huge number on y axis

Tags: python, matplotlib

Suppose I have two arrays:

```
Y = [1,2,3,4,5, 10000]
X = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

I want to have a plot like: plt.plot(X,Y). But, the 10,000 number is huge and thus it distorts my plot. Is there anyway to show 10000 on y axis such that the other values will also be seen properly.

Comment: Try exponential scaling?

Comment: plot it with a [logarithmic axis](https://matplotlib.org/2.0.0/examples/pylab_examples/log_demo.html)

Comment: I prefer to show 10000 as an string just a bit above 5. For me numbers 1 to 5 are important. 10000 is an outlier.

Comment: See [Is there a way to make a discontinuous axis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5656798/python-matplotlib-is-there-a-way-to-make-a-discontinuous-axis) and [Break // in x axis of matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32185411/break-in-x-axis-of-matplotlib)

Comment: See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45107420/2454357).