# Widen extremes of x-axis and compress lower part

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am drawing x-y plots and say my x-axis ranges from 0-2000. I am more interested in showing the behavior from x = say 0-10 and then x = 1500 - 2000.
And x = 11-1499 is not of much interest to me. However, I still want to keep that in the figure. So I want that if I can have more ticks(and widened axis) for x = 0 - 10 and and 1500-2000 and x = 11-1499 just a normal axis.
I could think of two ways --

1. Make x-axis logscale. This helps me elaborate only 0-10.
2. Introduce break in the x-axis as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32185411/break-in-x-axis-of-matplotlib). However, this removes middle part and I don't want that too.

Comment: You need two breaks, one at 10, the other at 1500. So you use 3 axes instead of 2. Apart the solution is the same as in the linked question.

Comment: So for first axis I will hide left spines for 2nd right and what for third?

Comment: For the left axes you hide the right spine, for the middle axes you hide both spines, for the right axes you hide the left spine.