# Broken axis slash marks inside bar chart in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart

I've seen matplotlib examples of placing the broken axis slash marks on the axes, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32185411/break-in-x-axis-of-matplotlib).

My questions, how can I place it where the bars are broken? Can this be done in a programmatic way for updating time-series plots month over month?

Below is an example of what I want done, using excel. Notice the tildes in the Paris June bar and the Madrid May bar. The tildes hide a portion of the bar it's covering.

[image: broken axis excel example]

I'm also providing easier sample data and what I've been able to do so far.

```
XX = pd.Series([200,400,100,1400],index=['x1','x2','x3','x4'])
fig, (ax1,ax2) = plt.subplots(2,1,sharex=True,
                         figsize=(5,6))
ax1.spines['bottom'].set_visible(False)
ax1.tick_params(axis='x',which='both',bottom=False)
ax2.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax2.set_ylim(0,500)
ax1.set_ylim(1200,1500)
ax1.set_yticks(np.arange(1000,1501,100))
XX.plot(ax=ax1,kind='bar')
XX.plot(ax=ax2,kind='bar')
for tick in ax2.get_xticklabels():
    tick.set_rotation(0)
d = .015  
kwargs = dict(transform=ax1.transAxes, color='k', clip_on=False)
ax1.plot((-d, +d), (-d, +d), **kwargs)      
ax1.plot((1 - d, 1 + d), (-d, +d), **kwargs)
kwargs.update(transform=ax2.transAxes)  
ax2.plot((-d, +d), (1 - d, 1 + d), **kwargs)  
ax2.plot((1 - d, 1 + d), (1 - d, 1 + d), **kwargs)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: What exactly is the problem? The answers in the linked question show how to do it (programmatically). Is is that you want to have a wavy symbol instead of the straight lines?

Comment: The symbols in the linked answer are only on the axis. The Excel image I shared has it on both the axis and the bars. How can I place the slashes or tildes on the bars themselves

Comment: You would place them at every position where the bar is larger than your limit for the lower plot (in this case 8M).

Comment: Can you provide code for how this would be done for the sample data I just provided? When I try to add the slashes on the x4 bar, it gets hidden because of the ylimit I set.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just to show the principle, you can put the same kind of line at every position where a bar exceeds the upper limit of the lower axes and also where a bar exceeds the lower limit of the upper axes.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

XX = pd.Series([200,400,100,1400],index=['x1','x2','x3','x4'])
fig, (ax1,ax2) = plt.subplots(2,1,sharex=True,
                         figsize=(5,6))
ax1.spines['bottom'].set_visible(False)
ax1.tick_params(axis='x',which='both',bottom=False)
ax2.spines['top'].set_visible(False)

bs = 500
ts = 1000

ax2.set_ylim(0,bs)
ax1.set_ylim(ts,1500)
ax1.set_yticks(np.arange(1000,1501,100))

bars1 = ax1.bar(XX.index, XX.values)
bars2 = ax2.bar(XX.index, XX.values)

for tick in ax2.get_xticklabels():
    tick.set_rotation(0)
d = .015  
kwargs = dict(transform=ax1.transAxes, color='k', clip_on=False)
ax1.plot((-d, +d), (-d, +d), **kwargs)      
ax1.plot((1 - d, 1 + d), (-d, +d), **kwargs)
kwargs.update(transform=ax2.transAxes)  
ax2.plot((-d, +d), (1 - d, 1 + d), **kwargs)  
ax2.plot((1 - d, 1 + d), (1 - d, 1 + d), **kwargs)

for b1, b2 in zip(bars1, bars2):
    posx = b2.get_x() + b2.get_width()/2.
    if b2.get_height() > bs:
        ax2.plot((posx-3*d, posx+3*d), (1 - d, 1 + d), color='k', clip_on=False,
                 transform=ax2.get_xaxis_transform())
    if b1.get_height() > ts:
        ax1.plot((posx-3*d, posx+3*d), (- d, + d), color='k', clip_on=False,
                 transform=ax1.get_xaxis_transform())
plt.show()
```

[image]

It doesn't look great, but can of course be adapted with a nicer shape.

Comment: Thank you! I can see adapting this to add the white space that should hide part of the bar

Answer (score 4):

I needed broken y-axis some time ago and created some code to do it. Now, I have submitted it to [PyPi](https://pypi.org/project/plotinpy/) so that others can use it. It's far from being a final version though. Any comments are welcome, and there is also the [GitHub project](https://github.com/masbicudo/PlotInPy), in which anyone can collaborate of course. Any issue, code and anything else is welcome.

Also, consider reading the following post. It gives some good reasons why a broken y-axis might not be desirable, before deciding on using it or not. One of the main points in my opinion is that breaking the y-axis makes the sense of proportion go away entirely. As it happens with limited y-axis ranges, it can be rather confusing to see a plot like this. That said, if used, I would recommend that the audience is made aware of the strange proportions that can arise from the use of this kind of plot.

- [Broken Y Axis in an Excel Chart](https://peltiertech.com/broken-y-axis-in-excel-chart/) at Peltier Tech Blog

Installing:

```
pip install plotinpy
```

Here is some example usages of the broken y-axis:

### Examples

#### Simple broken bars

```
plt.figure()
pnp.plot_bars_with_breaks(
    [1, 2, 30],
    [(15, 25)]
    )
plt.savefig("img/example1.png")
```

[image: Example 1]

#### Styled broken bars

```
plt.figure()
pnp.plot_bars_with_breaks(
    [1, 2, 30, 1000],
    [(15, 25), (50, 975)],
    style="~~",
    break_args={"hatch": '///'}
    )
plt.savefig("img/example2.png")
```

[image: Example 2]