# Leave out parts of plot by an Ellipsis

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, seaborn

I have a plot with histograms that are very far apart, and I want to leave out the whitespace by drawing ellipsis ("...") between the plots, if possible also leaving out the axis in that part.

The drawing below is just a sketch, and the distance between the histograms is usually much larger, this is just an example.

What I am getting:

[image: What I am Getting]

What I want:

[image: What I want]

Comment: See the [**`broken_axis`**](https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/broken_axis.html) example.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python/Matplotlib - Is there a way to make a discontinuous axis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5656798/python-matplotlib-is-there-a-way-to-make-a-discontinuous-axis)

Comment: See also [Break // in x axis of matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32185411/break-in-x-axis-of-matplotlib)

Comment: Thank you, yes it does! The ellipsis would be a nice-to-have but this is great too!