# Matplotlib Plot time series with different periodicity

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have 2 dfs. One of them has data for a month. Another one, averages for the past quarters. I wanna plot the averages in front of the monthly data. How can I do it? Please note that I am trying to plot averages as dots and monthly as line chart.

So far my best result was achieved by `ax1=ax.twiny()`, but still not ideal result as data point appear in throughout the chart, rather than just in front.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
from matplotlib.ticker import ScalarFormatter, FormatStrFormatter, FuncFormatter
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

date_base = pd.date_range(start='1/1/2018', end='1/30/2018')
df_base = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(30,4), columns=list("ABCD"), index=date_base)

date_ext = pd.date_range(start='1/1/2017', end='1/1/2018', freq="Q")
df_ext = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(4,4), columns=list("ABCD"), index=date_ext)

def drawChartsPlt(df_base, df_ext):

    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    number_of_plots = len(df_base.columns)
    LINE_STYLES = ['-', '--', '-.', 'dotted']

    colormap = plt.cm.nipy_spectral
    ax.set_prop_cycle("color", [colormap(i) for i in np.linspace(0,1,number_of_plots)])

    date_base = df_base.index
    date_base = [i.strftime("%Y-%m-%d") for i in date_base]

    q_ends = df_ext.index
    q_ends = [i.strftime("%Y-%m-%d") for i in q_ends]

    date_base.insert(0, "") #to shift xticks so they match chart
    date_base += q_ends

    for i in range(number_of_plots):
        df_base.ix[:-3, df_base.columns[i]].plot(kind="line", linestyle=LINE_STYLES[i%2], subplots=False, ax=ax)

    #ax.set_xticks(date_base)
    #ax.set_xticklabels(date_base)
    # ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(20))
    ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.LinearLocator(len(date_base)))
    ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(plt.FixedFormatter(date_base))
    fig.autofmt_xdate()
    # ax1=ax.twinx()
    ax1=ax.twiny()
    ax1.set_prop_cycle("color", [colormap(i) for i in np.linspace(0,1,number_of_plots)])

    for i in range(len(df_ext.columns)):
        ax1.scatter(x=df_ext.index, y=df_ext[df_ext.columns[i]])
    ax.set_title("Test")

    #plt.minorticks_off())
    ax.minorticks_off()
    #ax1.minorticks_off()
    #ax1.set_xticklabels(date_base)
    #ax1.set_xticklabels(q_ends)
    ax.legend(loc="center left", bbox_to_anchor=(1,0.5))

    ax.xaxis.label.set_size(12)
    plt.xlabel("TEST X Label")
    plt.ylabel("TEST Y Label")
    ax1.set_xlabel("Quarters")

    plt.show()

drawChartsPlt(df_base, df_ext)
```

Comment: You're code does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I ended up coding it is by saving quarterly index of df_ext to a temp variable, overwriting it with dates that are close to `df_base.index` using `pd.date_range(start=df_base.index[-1], periods=len(df_ext), freq='D')`, and the finally setting the dates that I need with `ax.set_xticklabels(list(date_base)+list(date_ext))`.

It looks like it could be achieved using broken axes as indicated [Break // in x axis of matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32185411/break-in-x-axis-of-matplotlib) and [Python/Matplotlib - Is there a way to make a discontinuous axis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5656798/python-matplotlib-is-there-a-way-to-make-a-discontinuous-axis?noredirect=1&lq=1), but I haven't tried that solution.