# How do I get plotly to display a graph object scatter plot (type='line') with rangebreaks to not display the excluded ranges?

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, plotly

I am currently trying to plot a line plot (eventually with multiple traces) as a graph object using plotly. It is based on time-series stock market prices and since I only need/have the data for certain days, I need to exclude the irrelevant ranges on the xaxis based on date or datetime values. My data set can be considered like this:

```
d = {'plotPrice': [107, 107.1, 107.2, 106.9, 107, 106.5, 106, 106.2, 106.8, 107], 
     'dateTime': [pd.Timestamp('2023-10-24 08:01:56.668000'), pd.Timestamp('2023-10-24 09:25:58.272'), pd.Timestamp('2023-10-26 11:42:09.199'),
                 pd.Timestamp('2023-10-26 14:54:06.095'),pd.Timestamp('2023-10-26 15:25:50.430'),pd.Timestamp('2023-10-30 09:15:33.546'),
                 pd.Timestamp('2023-10-30 11:34:44.861'),pd.Timestamp('2023-10-30 14:18:27.706'),pd.Timestamp('2023-10-30 15:02:33.771'),
                 pd.Timestamp('2023-10-30 16:30:37.412')]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

The data is based on tick data hence not organized in equal size intervals by for example 1-minute or similar and I can't aggregate it by time interval either for other reasons. This means that I need plotly to recognize the xaxis as a `type=date` axis in order to get it scaled correctly. My current function for plotting via plotly and applying rangebreaks looks like this:

```
def generate_plotly_line_plot(df, titlestr, ccy,saveBool=False):

    # Figure and Layout
    fig = go.Figure()
    fig.update_layout(
        autosize=False,
        width=1000,
        height=500,
        margin=dict(
            l=50,
            r=50,
            b=50,
            t=50,
            pad=4
        ),
        title=go.layout.Title(text=titlestr),
        showlegend=True,
        hovermode='x unified'
    )

    # Format x and y axis
    dateTime_date = df['dateTime'].apply(lambda x: x.date()).unique()
    df_date_range = pd.date_range(df['dateTime'].min(), df['dateTime'].max(), freq='1D').to_series().reset_index(
        drop=True).apply(lambda x: x.date())
    exclude_dates = [x.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') for x in df_date_range if x not in dateTime_date]

    fig.update_xaxes(
        title_text='Date',
        rangebreaks=[
            dict(values=exclude_dates)
        ],
        rangeslider_visible = True
    )

    # Add Traces
    for plot_col in df.columns[df.columns!='dateTime']:
        fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df['dateTime'],
                                 y=df[plot_col],
                                 mode='lines',
                                 name=plot_col,
                                 line=dict(
                                     width=.75
                                 ))
                      )

    fig.update_yaxes(
        title_text="Stock Price in "+ccy)

    fig.show()

generate_plotly_line_plot(df=df[['plotPrice', 'dateTime']],titlestr='Test', ccy='EUR')
```

The above script will give me the following plots
According to the above Example:
[plot with missing plot data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Rgad.png)
According to entire data:
[plot with plot data but daterange gaps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0NC8S.png)

The issue now is, that plotly seems to implement the rangebreaks but doesn't remove the excluded area on the xaxis causing massive gaps between the desired dates. Is there a way to make plotly properly remove the rangebreak gaps from the xaxis as well?

Thanks in advance!

I already tried the following things:

- Use rangebreaks in the form of `dict(bounds=[16.5, 9], pattern="hour")` or `dict(bounds=["sat", "mon"])`, but that doesn't work for me as I need to exclude specific dates also during the normal trading week.
- Reformatting the `exclude_dates` to strings including hour, minute, seconds and milliseconds.
  That results in the plot only showing the first date and not the entire period.
- Use `exclude_dates` on per second/minute level i.e. pass many more values as `exclude_dates`.
  This results in the plot only showing the first day of data as well.

Comment: maybe using matplotlib breaks is what you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32185411/break-in-x-axis-of-matplotlib

Comment: It depends on how strictly you want to check the time series, but do you need milliseconds? You can also easily draw it by changing the x-axis to categories. `fig.update_xaxes(type='category')`

Comment: Thank you @tetrisprogramming, I may be able to rebuild it using the clip function or brokenaxes package, but of course without the dynamic functionalities of plotly.

@r-beginners I don't necessarily need milliseconds, the issue with using `fig.update_xaxes(type='category')` is though, that the xaxis scale wont be correct anymore i.e. each tick/ data point will take up the same amount of space meaning that in my example the 24th Nov will take up 20% of the xaxis, the 26th will take up 30% and the 30th will take up 50% of the xaxis space.
Thank you both for the ideas so far!

Answer (score 0):

After trying to rebuild the time series plot using plotly using `rangebreaks` in different ways, I couldn't manage to get it working.

I then switched back to using the `brokenaxes` package and for more advanced plots the `transform=ax.transAxes` transformation in matplotlib. This at least allowed me to correctly scale the x-axis according to datetime, while breaking the x-axis per day. Note, that my data already excludes weekends and selected dates. Each script looks somewhat like these:

**brokenaxes:**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
from brokenaxes import brokenaxes

def matplotlib_price_plot(df):

    # Init
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20, 10))
    x_major_formatter  = mdates.DateFormatter("%Y-%m-%d\n%H:%M")
    
    # Get ax breaks
    date_ranges = []
    for d in df['date'].unique():
        temp = df[df['date']==d]
        date_ranges.append((temp['dateTime'].iloc[0], temp['dateTime'].iloc[-1]))
    date_ranges = tuple(date_ranges)
    
    # Init broken ax
    bax = brokenaxes(xlims=date_ranges, wspace=.03)
    
    # Plot values
    bax.plot(df['dateTime'], df['price'], c='darkorange', label='price', alpha=.5)
    bax.set_ylabel('Price in EUR')
    bax.legend()
    
    # Format Ticks
    for ax in bax.axs:
        ax.grid(which='major', axis='both')
        ax.xaxis.set_tick_params(labelsize=6)
        ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(x_major_formatter)
    
    return
```

**Output:**
[brokenaxes output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gyoTj.png)

**matplotlib `(ax.transAxes)`:**
NOTE: Here I needed to remove/ overwrite individual axes in order to get the desired result as you essentially combine multiple individual subplots into a single figure.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import matplotlib as mpl

def matplotlib_sector_price_plot(df):
    # Get ax breaks
    date_ranges = []
    for d in df['date'].unique():
        temp = df[df['date']==d]
        date_ranges.append((temp.index[0], temp.index[-1]))
    date_ranges = tuple(date_ranges)

    # Init fig
    fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, len(date_ranges), sharex=False, figsize=(25, 10))

    x_major_formatter  = mdates.DateFormatter("%d-%m\n%H:%M")

    stockTicker = 'CFR SW'
    stockCurrency = 'CHF'
    sectorTicker = 'ESIC GR'

    # Check whether 1-D or more and adjust tick size
    if len(axs) == 1:
        hour_tick_size = 1
    else:
        hour_tick_size = 2

    # Plot values
    for ax, dr in zip(axs, date_ranges):
        temp = df[(df.index>=dr[0])&(df.index<=dr[1])]
        ax.set_xlim(dr)
        kwargs = dict(transform=ax.transAxes, color='k', clip_on=False)
        d = 0.005
        if ax == axs[0] and len(axs) > 1: # First subplot for multi day
            ax.plot(temp['lastPx'], c='mediumblue', label=stockTicker + ' (Last)', linewidth=.75)
            ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
            ax.tick_params(labelright='off')
            ax.yaxis.tick_left()
            ax.set_ylabel('Stock Price in ' + stockCurrency)
            ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(mpl.ticker.StrMethodFormatter('{x:,.2f}'))
            ax.tick_params(axis='x', labelrotation=0)
            ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(mpl.ticker.LinearLocator(5))
            ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(x_major_formatter)
            ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.HourLocator(byhour=range(1,25),interval=hour_tick_size))
            ax.grid(which='major', axis='x')

            ax2 = ax.twinx()
            ax2.plot(temp['lastMidPt'], c='gold', label=sectorTicker + ' (Mid)', linewidth=.75)
            ax2.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
            ax2.tick_params(labelright='off')
            ax2.yaxis.set_ticks([])
            ax2.yaxis.set_major_formatter(mpl.ticker.StrMethodFormatter('{x:,.4f}'))

            ax.plot((1 - d, 1 + d), (-d, +d), **kwargs)
            ax.plot((1 - d, 1 + d), (1 - d, 1 + d), **kwargs)
        elif ax == axs[-1] and len(axs) > 1: # Last subplot for multi day
            line1 = ax.plot(temp['lastPx'], c='mediumblue', label=stockTicker + ' (Last)', linewidth=.75)
            ax.spines['left'].set_visible(False)
            ax.yaxis.tick_right()
            ax.yaxis.set_ticks_position('none')
            ax.yaxis.set_ticks([])
            ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(x_major_formatter)
            ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.HourLocator(byhour=range(1,25),interval=hour_tick_size))
            ax.tick_params(axis='x', labelrotation=0)
            ax.grid(which='major', axis='both')

            ax2 = ax.twinx()
            line2 = ax2.plot(temp['lastMidPt'], c='gold', label=sectorTicker + ' (Mid)', linewidth=.75)
            ax2.spines['left'].set_visible(False)
            ax2.tick_params(labelleft='off')
            ax2.set_ylabel('ETF Price in EUR')
            ax2.yaxis.tick_right()
            ax2.yaxis.set_major_locator(mpl.ticker.LinearLocator(5))
            ax2.yaxis.set_major_formatter(mpl.ticker.StrMethodFormatter('{x:,.4f}'))

            ax.plot((-d, +d), (1 - d, 1 + d), **kwargs)
            ax.plot((-d, +d), (-d, +d), **kwargs)
        elif len(axs) == 1: # 1-D plot
            line1 = ax.plot(temp['lastPx'], c='mediumblue', label=stockTicker + ' (Last)', linewidth=.75)
            ax.set_ylabel('Stock Price in ' + stockCurrency)
            ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(mpl.ticker.StrMethodFormatter('{x:,.2f}'))
            ax.tick_params(axis='x', labelrotation=0)
            ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(mpl.ticker.LinearLocator(5))
            ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(x_major_formatter)
            ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.HourLocator(byhour=range(1, 25), interval=hour_tick_size))
            ax.grid(True, which='major', axis='both')

            ax2 = ax.twinx()
            line2 = ax2.plot(temp['lastMidPt'], c='gold', label=sectorTicker + ' (Mid)', linewidth=.75)
            ax2.yaxis.set_major_locator(mpl.ticker.LinearLocator(5))
            ax2.yaxis.set_major_formatter(mpl.ticker.StrMethodFormatter('{x:,.4f}'))
            ax2.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.HourLocator(byhour=range(1, 25), interval=hour_tick_size))
            ax2.grid(True, which='major', axis='both')
        else: # Middle subplots for multi day
            ax.plot(temp['lastPx'], c='mediumblue', label=stockTicker + ' (Last)', linewidth=.75)
            ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
            ax.spines['left'].set_visible(False)
            ax.tick_params(labelright='off')
            ax.yaxis.set_ticks_position('none')
            ax.yaxis.set_ticks([])
            ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(x_major_formatter)
            ax.tick_params(axis='x', labelrotation=0)
            ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.HourLocator(byhour=range(1,25),interval=hour_tick_size))
            ax.grid(which='major', axis='both')

            ax2 = ax.twinx()
            ax2.plot(temp['lastMidPt'], c='gold', label=sectorTicker + ' (Mid)', linewidth=.75)
            ax2.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
            ax2.spines['left'].set_visible(False)
            ax2.yaxis.set_ticks_position('none')
            ax2.yaxis.set_ticks([])
            ax2.yaxis.set_major_formatter(mpl.ticker.StrMethodFormatter('{x:,.4f}'))

            ax.plot((1 - d, 1 + d), (-d, +d), **kwargs)
            ax.plot((1 - d, 1 + d), (1 - d, 1 + d), **kwargs)

            ax.plot((-d, +d), (1 - d, 1 + d), **kwargs)
            ax.plot((-d, +d), (-d, +d), **kwargs)

    lines = line1+line2
    labs = [l.get_label() for l in lines]
    axs[-1].legend(lines, labs, loc='upper right')

    fig.tight_layout()

    plt.show()
    return
```

**Output:**
[matplotlib transAxes output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GQZp4.png)

Overall, not really the same result as the plots are static and missing the plotly functionality, but at least what I wanted to achieve from a visualization perspective.